# Use of IF condition in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement, jstl

I have this line

```
<td><c:out value="${row.file_name}"/></td>
```

file_name is a column name from the mysql database table.
I want to check if file_name has some value,so I want to use the `IF condition`,but how do I pass `row.file_name`?
something like `if(row.file_name!=null){}`

**UPDATE**

```
<td><c:out value="${row.file_name}"/><br>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${row.file_name == null}">
         Null
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       <a href="downloadFileServlet?id=${row.id}">Download</a></td>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

In this case only the 2nd condition is executed even though the file_name is empty

Comment: use script tag to do the logic

Comment: What do you see as output for the first `<c:out>`? Also, you haven't closed `<td>` tag for `<c:when>`. Better to move the closing tag completely outside the `<c:choose>` tag.

Comment: download,i have a table..so on all download comes,and in the cell that has the file,there the name of the file along with the download comes

Comment: If you are also testing for empty file name, then you should use `empty` condition to test both null and empty. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, `if` is not a loop, it is just a statement. You can use [`<c:if>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html) tag for testing the value:

```html
<c:if test="${row.file_name != null}">
    Not Null   
</c:if>
```

And for Java `if-else` statement, JSTL tag equivalent is [`<c:choose>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/choose.html)(No, there is no `<c:else>`):

```html
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${row.file_name != null}">
        Not Null
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        Null
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Note that, `${row.file_name != null}` condition will be `true` only for `non-null` file name. And empty file name is not null. If you want to check for both `null` and empty file name, then you should use `empty` condition:

```html
<!-- If row.file_name is neither empty nor null -->
<c:when test="${!empty row.file_name}">
    Not empty
</c:when>
```

Comment: @Vidic For `if-else` you have to use `<c:choose>`, `<c:when>`, `<c:otherwise>` tags.

Comment: the first condition works fine but for the next condition it displays both the results,i.e of the 1st and 2nd condition

Comment: You mean, both `when` and `otherwise` is executing? That is not possible, unless you have not done anything wrong elsewhere. Did you copy the exact code?

Comment: @Vidic Can you show the exact code that you have, and what value are you getting for `row.file_name`? Check by printing it. Is it `null`?

Comment: this line threw an exception
`<c:when test="${!empty row.file_name}">`this is what i wrote `<c:when test="${!empty row.file_name}">
<a href="downloadFileServlet?id=${row.id}">Download</a>
</c:when></td>`

Comment: @Vidic What exception? Did you add a `<c:otherwise>` tag?

Comment: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Illegal use of &lt;when&gt;-style tag without &lt;choose&gt; as its direct parent

Comment: i need to add choose i guess

Comment: @Vidic You have to follow this order - `<c:choose>`, inside that one or multiple `<c:when>` followed by at least one `<c:otherwise>`. Copy paste the 2nd code snippet, and just change the condition in `<c:when>` there.

Comment: please help in this too if you could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258590/getting-a-filejpeg-png-pdf-along-with-extension-jsp

Answer (score 1):

You should use the if statement from the JSTL Core library, just like you use c:out

```
<c:if test="${empty row.file_name}">File name is null or empty!</c:if>
```

Comment: `empty` does test for both `null` and empty file_name, only if OP needs it.

Comment: i tried this but doesnt work `<td><c:out value="${row.file_name}"/><br>

<c:if test="${empty row.file_name}">File name is null or empty!</c:if>
<c:otherwise <a href="downloadFileServlet?id=${row.id}">Download</a></c:otherwise></td>`

Answer (score 1):

Without `<c:if/>` you can test `file_name` is  `null` by using `default`.

```
 <td><c:out value="${row.file_name}" default="NULL FILE"/></td>
```